# OSx DartLang - How to Reset Workspace into DartLang Editor?

Tags: eclipse, macos, dart, workspace, dart-editor

I've moved out some "windows console" into another screen to best develop app. But after restarting DartEditor this windows are empty, I'm not able to close... ect. How can I reset workspace? [image]

I'm Working on Osx Platform.

### Tested Steps:

- after found a bug i have "update" entire DartEditor folder with new version, without cleaning other cache files. The bug aren't solved.
- Only after complete cleaning files with "App Cleaner" and reinstalling Dart Editor the bug are solved.

Answer (score 2):

perhaps be solved by deleting the

> `/ Library / Application Support / Darteditor`